# Place an object where Raycast points but taking collisions into account in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, raycasting

I am trying to place an object where my Raycast points (where the Raycast finds a collision). But what I get is what you see in the image attached (2 different cases). The object is placed where I am pointing indeed, but I would like to take the collisions into account so that the objects do not go through each other.
Every object has its own Collider.

[image: Two different cases in which objects are positioned through each other]

Does anybody know how to solve this? Thank you.

Jan

EDIT:

I have tried to implement the solution given by @31eee384 like this:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Game.MuebleAEditarGO.transform.position = CameraFacing.transform.position;
if (Game.MuebleAEditarGO.GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody>().SweepTest(CameraFacing.transform.rotation * Vector3.forward, out hit, 50f))
{
    Game.MuebleAEditarGO.transform.position += CameraFacing.transform.forward * hit.distance;
}
```

MuebleAEditarGO is a RigidBody. The walls (and the house in general) are not rigidbodies and they have MeshoColliders each.

But then I get a solution that partially works. It appears to be working fine when the RaycastHit finds only one collision (see the image below).

[image: Image showing the problem with rigidbodies and collisions]

Comment: Something like this could work:
While the placed object intersects anything
{
   Move it along the line Raycast intersection point -> camera origin, closer to the camera.
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct solution is one that uses Unity's physics engine: [`Rigidbody.SweepTest`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.SweepTest.html). It sweeps your actual rigidbody with its colliders (no abstraction like a bounding box or manual distance checking), and it will do so with all the optimization and generalized calculations a physics engine can offer.

To use it, check the example on the doc page for `SweepTest`, copied here for completeness:

```
RaycastHit hit;
if (rb.SweepTest(transform.forward, out hit, collisionCheckDistance))
{
    aboutToCollide = true;
    distanceToCollision = hit.distance;
}
```

Then use `transform.forward * distanceToCollision` to determine how far to move the object until it makes its first collision. For example:

```
RaycastHit hit;
couch.transform.position = transform.position;
if (couch.SweepTest(transform.forward, out hit, 50f))
{
    couch.transform.position += transform.forward * hit.distance;
}
```

Make sure that your objects are on different physics layers so the couch doesn't collide with the player's collider(s).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @31eee384. However, I do not seem to understand it well, because it does not work, hit returns null. I am using only the second script you posted applying it to the Center Eye Anchor of my Oculus Rift camera (which should be the same as a normal camera). This is what I have so far: RaycastHit hit; if (Game.MuebleAEditarGO.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().SweepTest(CameraFacing.transform‌​.forward, out hit, 50f)) { Game.MuebleAEditarGO.transform.position = CameraFacing.transform.forward * hit.distance; }

Comment: @user2211939 I've confirmed that it works as-is in a test project. I put the code in a script on the main camera in an update function (either `Update` or `FixedUpdate` works, depending on what you're doing with it). Maybe you're misinterpreting an error message: does the object really have a rigidbody? (The rigidbody should also be kinematic to avoid accumulating downwards velocity while it's held in the air.)

Comment: I edited the post with your solution. I still get some problems. However, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user2211939 You said "when the RaycastHit finds only one collision", but `SweepTest` only ever outputs the nearest hit. What makes you think it's finding more than one hit in the error case? It seems to me like your mesh collider is most likely different than the display mesh, making the situation confusing--it's unlikely that `SweepTest` is failing to work as the docs say. I'd suggest starting from the simplest scenario (all walls are boxes) and work your way up, testing each model until you find the first specific case that doesn't work. Otherwise it's hard to get enough info to help.

Comment: Found it. The problem is that it doesn't work with Mesh Colliders. Unfortunately, all the walls surrounding the house are the same object, meaning that I must use mesh colliders; otherwise, the camera would be placed above the house because it would collide with the box. I really don't know yet how to solve this, but your solution was right, so thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2211939 Hmm, nicely isolated, but that's surprising--the docs claim that "concave mesh colliders [on the rigidbody] will not work, although they can be detected in the scene by the sweep". I believe you, though... meshes aren't typically supported very well in physics engines. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your question **highly depends on the specifications you have**. 
You can start by calculating the width of the spawning GameObject's collider and apply an offset, but it will only work when facing planes. Adding raycast around goal position will allow you to manage corners too.
Managing more general situations (irregular surfaces, corners smaller than your objects, etc) will lead to more complicated solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of Unity's `OnTriggerEnter` on `OnTriggerExit` methods to determine if it is OK for an object to be placed in a certain location.

For example, you could keep track of the number of objects the object you are placing has collided with, by adding one to a number every time something enters it's trigger.  Then, when something leaves its trigger, subtract one from that number.  If the number of colliders in your object is zero, then it is safe to place the object.

```
public class PlaceableObject : MonoBehaviour 
{
    int CollidersInTrigger = 0;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        CollidersInTrigger++;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) 
    {
        CollidersInTrigger--;
    }

    bool CanPlace()
    {
        return CollidersInTrigger == 0;
    }
}
```

Note that for this to work, while your object is in "Placing Mode" its collider's IsTrigger property must be set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

**Fallout 4** kinda way:

you most probably have a reference to the object you are holding. Attach a script to it that will hold a public bool variable to mark if it's intersecting anything at any given moment. toggle that bool's value in OnTriggerEnter() and OnTriggerExit() . if the bool is true, do not allow the user to put the object down (and maybe use a another layer of red on the object or something to let them know)

**Portal 2** way:

you most probably have some script that is describing your objects you can grab. add a size variable to it describing proxy size of your object - a bit more then largest scale on one axis. (e.g. if couch is 2x5x10 size, let the proxy be 11)

disable the collider on the object you are holding. thus raycasting will work on everything else you look at.

if the ray hits anything take the ray.point. from that point take some arbitrary value that is bigger than size of your object and move your object that much towards you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your aim is to spawn different objects in different places.

I see 2 approaches here that can be combined.

1. You have objects-free zones and randomly spawn objects there. But there can be a problem if you can't make this zone object free. At least you can check with OverlapSphere or something whether your area is free. If not, you choose another area to check and spawn at random position within this zone
2. You "drop" your object from height where it is impossible to spawn inside other objects. Than you can let object fall or trace vertically position before obstacle and spawn at this point.